# Sharepoint Calculated Column to switch image onclick

Tags: image, onclick, sharepoint-2013, calculated-columns

I've hit a bump!  I'm trying to create a calculated column which will display a picture (A).  When that picture(A) is clicked I want the picture to switch to picture(B).

I've tried the following line, but I'm getting NOWHERE with this - please help.  Sharepoint 2013

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Status),"",("<A HREF="&Status&" onclick='changeImage().src='picture(B)'><img src='Picture(A)' style='height:45px; width:90px;' /></a>"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me just advice you to improve your javascript skills as your initial javascript is just, well, totally wrong.

You need something like this:

```
<A HREF="#" onclick="document.getElementById('mypicture').src='pic2.jpg'"><img id='mypicture' src='pic1.jpg' style='height:45px; width:90px;' /></a>
```

I leave it to you to correctly embed it in the calculated field ;-)

One hint i always give: you can simulate the calcultated fields formulas in plain Excel to see if they would work correctly.

EDIT:

**What happens?**

- As you see i gave an id (unique identifier) to the img element
- With this we can use a document method to get the item through its id (document.getElementById('theid')).
- Then we can get or set properties on the elements attributes (like src).
- For example we could also set the style on the element by doing document.getElementById('theid').style.backgroundColor='red';

We can also wrap this up into a function like this:

```
<script>
function setPicture(mypicture){
var element = document.getElementById('theid');
element.src=mypicture;
element.style.backgroundColor='red';
}
</script>
```

Here we use a variable to store the element

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:setPicture('pictureB.jpg');">click me</a>
```

This should give you a start but remember this is very basic stuff.

ps: can you accept the answer if it helped you? tnx :)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance!  I'm new to all of this and as usual, I start with the hard stuff and learn as I go.  I appreciate the guidance and will give it a whirl!